# System Identification with large Input/Output Data

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

I have some questions about system identification.
I made some measurement of current step (input) and voltage response(output) and I want to fine the parameters of my impedance.
The sample rate is 1000 samples/s so that I have a very large list of current and voltage samples include noise (40000 Samples).
My voltage is U(kT) and current is I(kT) where k=1,2,3,.....40000.

1. to filter the noise I used `ExponentialMovingaverage`; is there any other possibility to filter the noise from the list?
2. in *Mathematica* there is a function with the name `NonlinearModelfit` to find system parameters. Is there any other possibility to find the system parameters like nonlinear Least Square?

Answer (score 1):

1. Apart from `ExponentialMovingaverage` there are several other functions that you can use to filter the noise. `MovingAverage` and `MovingMedian` come to mind. `ListConvolve`, `GaussianFilter`, `MeanFilter`, `LowpassFilter` (v9) would probably work too.
2. `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`, `FindFit`. For a few specific situations `ProbitModelFit` and `LogitModelFit`

Comment: Thank you,
How can i determine the Cutoff Frequency of the LowpassFilter. i know that Fc<Fs/2 also Fc<500Hz.
but what is the optimal cutoff Frequency to make the LowpassFilter better than ExponentialMovingAverage.

Comment: @NimoBradly First, you should provide `LowpassFilter` with information about the sample rate, otherwise the cutoff frequency doesn't mean what you want it to. You can use the `SampleRate` option for that. What would be the best cutoff frequency depends on the typical frequency range of your signals and noise. Perhaps `Manipulate` would be useful here.