# System Identification from test data

Tags: matlab, control-systems

I've been looking for a way to model a simple SISO system from test data using Mathematica.

Something similar to MATLAB's System Identification Toolkit, that estimates a transfer function from the data would be great.

Is something like this possible in Mathematica?

Comment: I googled "system identification mathematica" and I see few packages and articles on this. For example [A System Identification Package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6444/) and [Identification Using Input­Output Data](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4796/) and [system-identification-with-large-input-output-data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17580/system-identification-with-large-input-output-data) and [A System, Signals and Identification Toolbox in Mathematica with Symbolic Capabilities](http://www.ifac-papersonline.net/Detailed/39669.html)

Comment: What do you need? I take Fourier transforms of the input and output and take the ratio to get a frequency response function.  From then onwards I do pole zero identification. This is a frequency domain approach.  Would this fit your needs?

Comment: Have you see then [Control Systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ControlSystems.html) guide and the related [Basic Systems Modeling](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Modeling.html) guide?

Comment: I am now doing just that. I have been using "Mastering System Identification in 100 Exercises" by J. Schoukens (et al) as a reference. In particular see problems 11 and 58. From Mathematica all you need is the LeastSquares command.

Answer (score 1):

Jonas Sjöberg has written an identification package, but I just can't find how to buy it or download it. You can find papers and presentations, but nothing else.

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5451/
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271456417_A_Mathematica_Toolbox_for_Signals_Systems_and_Identification